# Wordpress redirect based on the presence of a cookie

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect, cookies

First off, I am a complete amateur when it comes to coding, but I've been reading hundreds of posts on Stack Overflow and other websites in an attempt to string together the right PHP code to make my website behave in a certain way. It's probably going to look terrible and be formatted wrong, but I hope the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish comes through.

Before we get into the code, the basic idea is this: when someone comes to my e-commerce website I'd like to present them with three (or more) "brands". When they click on their favorite brand and go the brand page, the website should drop a cookie in their browser. When they return to the website at a later date, I'd like the website to automatically redirect to their chosen brand page rather than presenting the three choices again.

The simplified code I've created as a proof of concept uses two brand options, where two cookies with the same name but different values are placed based on when the visitor goes to the particular brand page. Only the second cookie value (brand_2) causes the redirect in this simplified code. The first cookie, (value "brand_1") drops in automatically when the visitor comes to the site. I don't love that solution or even know if I need to do that, but it seems to work to a degree. When the visitor goes to the brand 2 page, the cookie value changes to "brand_2" as it should. When they go to the brand 1 page, the cookie value reverts back to Brand_1 as it was when they first arrived on site.

Here is the code for the cookies, not perfect but it appears to work:

```
function brand_cookies() {
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['brands'])){
        setcookie('brands', 'brand_1', time()+3600*24*365*3, 
SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, true);
    }elseif(is_page('brand1') || is_page('brand2')){
        if($_COOKIE['brands'] == 'brand_2'){
            setcookie('brands', 'brand_1', time()+3600*24*365*3, 
SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, true);
    }elseif($_COOKIE['brands'] == 'brand_1'){
        setcookie('brands', 'brand_2', time()+3600*24*365*3, 
SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, true);
        }   
    }   
}
add_action( 'wp', ‘brand_cookies',10,1);
```

The part that doesn't work is my wp_redirect, which causes the white screen of death when I add it below the above code in my functions.php file in wordpress. It does work to a degree though, as when the cookie "brand_2" is present, the website does redirect to the brand 2 page of the site. It's just all white.

Here is the code for the redirect:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', ‘brand_redirect’ );

function brand_redirect(){
    // do your check and call wp_redirect here
    if($pagename !='home' ) {
        if($_COOKIE['brands'] == 'brand_2' ) 
            wp_redirect( 'http://test.site.com/brand2' ) ;
            exit; }

}
```

My ultimate goal is to add more cookies to the upper code for my three or more brands and their associated pages, and then create the corresponding redirect in the code below. Hopefully this all makes sense! Any help you could offer on what I'm doing wrong that is causing the white screen of death would be appreciated! Thank you for your help!

UPDATE:

Using Will Hine's suggestion for the top script worked absolutely perfectly for getting cookies added to the browser based on when the visitor to the site reached a particular brand page. Huge thanks to him for helping me with this! Here's his script:

```
function brand_cookies() {

    $brands = [
       'brand1' => 'brand_1',
       'brand2' => 'brand_2',
       'brand3' => 'brand_3'
    ];

    foreach ($brands as $page => $cookie) {
        if (is_page($page)) {
        setcookie('brands', $cookie, time()+3600*24*365*3, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, true);
        }
    }
}
```

I thought I was starting to figure out redirects and attempted to write my own script based on Will's script above to trigger a re-direct from the home page to the appropriate brand page. I only set it to redirect based on one of the brand cookies rather than all three just as a test. Unfortunately, when I uploaded the script into my functions.php file the entire site crashed including the wordpress dashboard. I had to go through my cPanel to reupload the original Functions.php file without the redirect script. Here's my site crashing script below, hopefully over the next couple of days I can figure out a working solution.

```
if( $pagename !=('home'))  {
    if (isset($_COOKIE['brands'])){
        if($_COOKIE['brands'] == 'brand_2' )
            header('Location: http://test.site.com/brand2/');
        exit;
    }
}
```

Here is another version I tried using all three brand cookies, which caused too many redirects in the browser when I tested it out:

```
function brand_redirect(){
    if($pagename !='home' ) {
        if($_COOKIE['brands'] == 'brand_1' ) 
            header('Location: http://test.site.com/brand1'); }
    elseif($pagename !='home' ) {
        if($_COOKIE['brands'] == 'brand_2' ) 
            header('Location: http://test.site.com/brand2'); }
    elseif($pagename !='home' ) {
        if($_COOKIE['brands'] == 'brand_3' ) 
            header('Location: http://test.site.com/brand3'); }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'brand_redirect' );
```

Comment: This looks generally right. Easy problems to look out for: is there anything being sent to the browser before the redirect? That will stop the redirect.

And is the cookie getting set right?

I would print_r($_COOKIE) at the top of your pages to see what's making it.

OR: Look at your site with Chrome, Click "View-> Developer -> Developer Tools", then click "Application" -- then on the left you can select "cookies" to see what cookies are getting set.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! My first step has been to add the top code to the functions.php file and test the site. That seems to work; when I use chrome, the brand_1 cookie swaps out for the brand_2 cookie when I go to the brand 2 page. When I add the wp_redirect code, the entire site is white; however, with the brand_2 cookie in place, it does automatically redirect to the brand 2 page like I want it to. I just cant figure out why everything this white.

Comment: an all white page often means an error. do you have access to the error logs?

Comment: I should have them, I'll have to dig around a bit and see if I can find them. Its my website, but I'm pretty clueless as to how the back end works. I stay on the wordpress dashboard for the most part. I'll check into it! Thanks for leading me in the right direction, Will!

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not helping you more. 

I just checked wordpress' docs. Try adding this to the top of your functions.php file:

    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

That might make errors (if errors are happening, and it seems like they are) be printed to the screen so you can see what they are.

Comment: I ended up finding the PHP errorlog file in my cPanel File manager, It does look like my redirect caused an error: [05-Jan-2018 11:39:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '‘brand_redirect’' not found or invalid function name in /home/theame52/public_html/Test/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286 I'm not sure what all that means just yet, but at least it gives me something to go on.

Comment: try moving the add_action( 'template_redirect', ‘brand_redirect’ ); to below the brand_redirect function, so that it's already defined before you call add_action

Comment: Looks like when I try moving the add_action down below it just disables the re-direct entirely. The re-direct itself definitely seems to be what is blowing up the site, when I remove it and leave only the cookie script it works as intended (other than the redirect of course). I think the PHP warning I listed off earlier no longer applies, that warning is from a few days ago; after I adjusted the function that warning seems to have gone away, or at least I haven't gotten a new one with todays date.

Comment: Hmm. No error. Odd. I'm sure this isn't it: but maybe try closing up those braces. Could it be the "exit;" is firing when you don't want. What I mean by "closing up the braces" is to have an opening and closing brace for "If $_COOKIE == brand2, that bit. Right now you don't, so the closing brace after "exit" is closing out the If ($pagename != 'home'). But other than that I'm out of ideas!

Comment: I think I've solved the redirect issue by getting rid of the wp_redirect entirely. When I test it with the original top script, the site stays running as it should (no more white screen), and it redirects from the home page to the brand page like I want. I updated my question to show the new redirect script. My next big thing is to get the cookies to only drop in the browser when the visitor reaches any one of the three pages. Right now the upper script drops the Brand_1 cookie into the browser on the home page, which prevents me from redirecting to the brand 1 page. Getting closer!

Comment: In the top script, change your original IF to this: if(!isset($_COOKIE['brands']) && is_page('brand1')) {

Comment: That worked perfectly for solving that problem! Thank You! Now there are no cookies added when I first reach the home page, only when I go to the brand 1 or brand 2 pages - which is exactly what I was wanting. Looks like I need to do more work to my redirect script though, as when it is in place, once I go to the brand 2 page and the brand_2 cookie is added, the site redirects to the brand 2 page always, even if I try to go to Brand 1 to swap the cookies out. I've noticed in Chrome when I highlight any link it shows the brand 2 page when the brand 2 cookie is in place with the redirect.

Comment: What pages should re-set the cookie? Like, if you want the site to redirect them to their brand on subsequent visit -- what page should NOT redirect?  And how does the user get there?

Comment: I sell muscle car parts for Ford, Chevy, and Dodge vehicles. I'd like the home page to be seen once, where the visitor selects their brand of choice and then the site takes them to that brand's "home page". When they come back to the site I don't want them to see the three choices anymore, instead I'd like to just redirect them to their brand of choice. I'll of course have links to the other two brand pages in case they want to switch. When any of the three main brand pages are reached, it should reset the cookie to trigger the site to redirect to that particular brand's page upon return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. This will set a cookie only when someone lands on a brand page.

The keys of the array $brands are the page identifiers. The corresponding values are cookie that should get set on those pages.

```
function brand_cookies() {

    $brands = [
       'brand1' => 'brand_1',
       'brand2' => 'brand_2',
       'brand3' => 'brand_3'
    ];

    foreach ($brands as $page => $cookie) {
        if (is_page($page)) {
        setcookie('brands', $cookie, time()+3600*24*365*3, 
SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false, true);
        }
    }
}
```

For the second one, I think you only want to set the cookie on the home page.

```
function brand_redirect(){
    $brands = [
        'brand_1' => 'http://test.site.com/brand1',
        'brand_2' => 'http://test.site.com/brand2',
        'brand_3' => 'http://test.site.com/brand1'
    ];

    if($pagename =='home' && isset($_COOKIE['brands'])) { // only on home page
        foreach ($brands as $cookie => $redirect_page) {
            if ($_COOKIE['brands'] == $cookie) {
                header("Location: $redirect_page"); 
            }
        }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'brand_redirect' );
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!! Thank you!! I've been playing around over the past couple of days with adding the redirect code to it, at one point I crashed the site completely and had to go through my cPanel to re-upload the footer.php script without the redirect present. So, still a work in progress on that, but your cookie script is exactly what I needed to solve the first part.

Comment: I've just updated my original question with a few updated re-direct scripts. Hopefully they make sense!

Comment: That solved the problem! At first when I added it in, it didn't do anything, positive or negative. Played around with it for a bit and discovered if I change the if statement from "if($pagename ==" to "if(is_page('home')" it worked. I have no idea why that is, but it does work! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response this saved me!!